# Powershell Get property 2 levels down

Tags: powershell, properties

How's it going flackoverstow,

I'm brand new to powershell and am seemingly having trouble retrieving properties two levels down for the source (aka: I can get a property of an object such as $foo.bar, but not a property of said property such as $foo.bar.soap)

I have the following code:

```
param (
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)]$Output = ".\OrphanedGPTs.txt",
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)]$Domain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
)

$strGCPath = "LDAP://" + $Domain.Name
$oCmd = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.command
$oConnection = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.connection
$oConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
$oConnection.Open("ADs Provider" )

$oCmD.ActiveConnection = $oConnection

$strADOQuery = "<"+ $strGCPath + ">;(objectCategory=group);distinguishedName;subtree"

$oCmd.CommandText = $strADOQuery

$TopLevel = $oCmd.Execute() #this works
$Fields = $oRecordSet.Fields #this works
$Name = $Fields.Name #this doesn't seem work
$TopLevel.MoveNext()

$TopLevel #this works
Write-Output "-----------------------"
$Fields #this works
Write-Output "-----------------------"
$Name #this returns nothing
Write-Output "-----------------------"
$TopLevel.Fields.Name #This also return nothing
Write-Output "-----------------------"
```

Which outputs the following:

```
    Properties       : System.__ComObject
    AbsolutePosition : 2
    ActiveConnection : System.__ComObject
    BOF              : False
    Bookmark         : 1
    CacheSize        : 1
    CursorType       : 3
    EOF              : False
    Fields           : System.__ComObject
    LockType         : 1
    MaxRecords       : 0
    RecordCount      : 932
    Source           : <LDAP://company.com>;(objectCategory=group);distinguishedName;subtree
    AbsolutePage     : 1
    EditMode         : 0
    Filter           : 0
    PageCount        : 94
    PageSize         : 10
    Sort             : 
    Status           : 0
    State            : 1
    CursorLocation   : 2
    MarshalOptions   : 0
    DataSource       : System.__ComObject
    ActiveCommand    : System.__ComObject
    StayInSync       : True
    DataMember       : 
    Index            : 

    -----------------------
    Properties      : System.__ComObject
    ActualSize      : 234
    Attributes      : 32
    DefinedSize     : 4000
    Name            : distinguishedName
    Type            : 202
    Value           : CN=blank,OU=blank,OU=blank 
              Groups,DC=company,DC=com
    Precision       : 255
    NumericScale    : 255
    OriginalValue   : 
    UnderlyingValue : 
    DataFormat      : 
    Status          : 0

    -----------------------
    -----------------------
    -----------------------
```

If the code worked like I wanted it to, there should have been "distinguishedName" or something printed between the dotted lines at the bottom.

How can I get $TopLevel.Fields.Name ?

Comment: `Fields` is an ADOCollection object, so you will have to enumerate over the collection and get the `Name` of each one. I have no experience with ADO or COM, so I can't give a real answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me point out that while you can use PowerShell on COM objects, there is usually a better alternative, and in this case, it is the ActiveDirectory module:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADDomain
```

Complete documentation on this module can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx).  But, let's answer your question.  Normally, your syntax will work, but not for COM properties.  For example, you can do this:

```
$TopLevel.Fields.Count    # returns 1 on my computer
```

But Name is a COM property, so you need to use `Select-Object`:

```
$TopLevel.Fields | Select-Object *

Properties      : System.__ComObject
ActualSize      : 194
Attributes      : 32
DefinedSize     : 4000
Name            : distinguishedName
Type            : 202
Value           : CN=Exchange Organization Administrators,OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups,DC=XXXXXXXX,DC=XXX
Precision       : 255
NumericScale    : 255
OriginalValue   : 
UnderlyingValue : 
DataFormat      : 
Status          : 0
```

So, to answer your specific question (how to get $TopLevel.Fields.Name), you would do this:

```
$name = $TopLevel.Fields | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```